# Angular2 call observer next from child object

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I'll try to explain this as best I can.

I have a service that contains an observable class that performs tasks to update itself. That observable class needs to be pushed out to the app using the observer located in the service. How can I call that observer from the child without creating some sort of dependency loop?

Here is a rough example:

```
class MyService {
  subClass$: Observable<SubClass>;
  _subClassObserver: Observer<SubClass>;

  constructor(private _subClassStore: SubClass){
    this.subClass$ = new Observable(observer => {
      this._subClassObserver = observer
    }).share();
  }

  pushData(){
    this._subClassObserver.next(this._subClassStore)
  }
}

class SubClass {
  displayData: string;
  displayData2: number;

  constructor(){
    socket.on('setData', function(obj){
      this.displayData = obj.dd1;
      this.displayData2 = obj.dd2;
      //How to call pushData() in MyService from here to push data to app?
    }
  }
}
```

_subClassStore is updating through a stream coming in from socket.io. How do I let MyService know when the SubClass data changes so that it can push it using _subClassObserver.next(_subClassStore)?

**EDIT:**
I added more details to the example above to show how they are related and utilized.

SubClass is just a listener for a stream of data coming from socket.io and saving the information into the class. It starts listening when MyService is constructed.

The goal of MyService is to provide a bunch these sub classes that can be subscribed to across the app. Each one would allow access to a different data stream and the associated data, but all would be contained within a single service.

The question is how to call the pushData() function in the parent so that it keeps the stream updated for subscribers in the app.

**Edit 2:**

This might help. below is how it would be written as a service without the sub class. The only reason why I'm not doing this is because there are a substantial amount of these listeners being stored to Observables and abstracting them out into classes makes the information much easier to manage but pushing it to the app is what I can't figure out:

```
class MyService {
  class1$: Observable<DataStream>;
  _class1Observer: Observer<DataStream>;
  _class1Store: DataStream;

  constructor(){
    this._class1store = {displayData: 'hello', displayData2: 0};

    this.class1$ = new Observable(observer => {
      this._class1Observer = observer
    }).share();

    socket.on('setData', function(obj){
      this._class1Store.displayData = obj.dd1;
      this._class1Store.displayData2 = obj.dd2;
      this._class1Observer.next(this._class1Store)
    }
  }

interface DataStream = {
   displayData: string;
   displayData2: number;
}
```

Comment: I guess you need to provide more context about how these components are related.

Comment: I provided a bit more info. This might be a bit too complicated to try to explain without a substantial code example, so if it's still not making any sense just let me know and I will delete it to prevent confusing others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `function(obj)` use `()=>` otherwise `this` won't ponit to the `MyService` instance.

```
  constructor(){
    socket.on('setData', (obj) =>{
      this.displayData = obj.dd1;
      this.displayData2 = obj.dd2;
      //How to call pushData() in MyService from here to push data to app?
    }
  }
```

I'm not sure but I think `socket` is prone to run outside Angulars zone.
Try also

```
  constructor(zone:NgZone){
    socket.on('setData', (obj) =>{
      zone.run(() => {
        this.displayData = obj.dd1;
        this.displayData2 = obj.dd2;
      //How to call pushData() in MyService from here to push data to app?
      });
    }
  }
```

To be able to call a method in `MyService` from `SubClass`, `SubClass` needs a reference to `MyService`

```
class MyService {
  subClass$: Observable<SubClass>;
  _subClassObserver: Observer<SubClass>;

  constructor(private _subClassStore: SubClass){
    _subClassStore.myService = this;
    this.subClass$ = new Observable(observer => {
      this._subClassObserver = observer
    }).share();
  }

  pushData(){
    this._subClassObserver.next(this._subClassStore)
  }
}

class SubClass {
  displayData: string;
  displayData2: number;
  myService:MyService;

  constructor(zone:NgZone){
    socket.on('setData', (obj) =>{
      zone.run(() => {
        this.displayData = obj.dd1;
        this.displayData2 = obj.dd2;
        this.myService.pushData();
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does MyService referencing SubClass and SubClass referencing MyService not create an infinite loop? Or is it just providing the reference to the class and not an instance of the class. Meaning a loop would only be created if they assigned each other to a variable within each other? Ex: the parent creating a child instance that creates a parent instance, repeated.

Comment: Creating a loop this way doesn't cause any issues. It would cause problems for example if DI had to resolve the loop which is not supported (when `MyService` requires `SubClass` in constructor parameters and `SubClass` requires `MyService` in constructor parameters would not work).